# Nginx logs are not writing

Tags: docker, nginx, openshift, nginx-config

In my Nginx I can't see logs are updating.

Below is the config

```
/etc/nginx # more nginx.conf

user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

I can see file is there in here `/var/log/nginx`

Below is the access status

```
/var/log/nginx # ls -lh
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          11 Jan 22  2020 access.log -> /dev/stdout
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          11 Jan 22  2020 error.log -> /dev/stderr
```

Just wondering what is missing in config.
Just note that this nginx running on a docker container inside `openshift` POD

Comment: Can you check if `access.log` has write permissions for the nginx user? Also try reloading your nginx server after making the changes. Do you get anything in `error.log`?

Comment: @NamanArora I updated the access status in the question.

Comment: @SMPH you found a solution for that problem? I have the same problem now running nginx with official docker image.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

Since the author is running Nginx inside a Docker container, use the command `docker logs container-name` to view both Nginx access and error logs.

For more information, visit this [Nginx document](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-docker/#log) and this [Docker document](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/).

<s>Original answer:</s>

<s>Your existing `access.log` and `error.log` files are just symbolic links to the [device files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr`. That's why you can't see any updates to them. So stop Nginx, then delete those files, then start Nginx again, then visit your website, you should see those files start to have new logs.</s>

Comment: I deleted those two files and was trying to re start Nginx with `nginx -s reload` after login to the container and from `usr/sbin/` folder where `nginx` exist, But was unable to restart.

Comment: @SMPH Oops! You didn't say that you're running Nginx inside a Docker container. If you can log in to your container, try to restore the deleted files using this command `ln -sf /proc/self/fd/1 /dev/stdout && ln -sf /proc/self/fd/2 /dev/stderr && ln -sf /proc/self/fd/1 /var/log/nginx/access.log && ln -sf /proc/self/fd/2 /var/log/nginx/error.log`. After that, restart your container and see my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, actually container running inside openshift POD, I have updated the question. Does that make any further difference to you answer?

Comment: @SMPH Sorry, I have no experience working with openshift POD.